# Jquery mobile popup not opening when encoded parameters in url

Tags: jquery, url, jquery-mobile, popup, encode

I'm using jQuery Mobile 1.4.5, my popups are working correctly but not in one specific case : when there are encoded parameters in url.

Example : 
When my page is [domain]/test?param1=14/03/2015

=> WORKING

---

When my page is [domain]/test?param1=14%2F03%2F2015

=> NOT WORKING

When I Click on button to open popup, url goes to [domain]/test?param1=14%2F03%2F2015#help-popup and popup is not showing

---

Code for the popup and the button :
http://jsfiddle.net/ndccjjmo/

```
<div id="help-popup" class="box box-primary" data-role="popup">
    <div class="box-header">
        <h2 class="box-title">Aide</h2>  
        <div class="box-tools pull-right">
            <a data-rel="back" class="btn btn-sm btn-default">Close</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-body">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#help-popup" class="btn btn-default" data-position-to="window" data-rel="popup"  data-transition="slidedown">Open popup</a>
```

Does someone have an idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Does it work if you open the popup via javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/ndccjjmo/1/

Comment: Hello,thx for replying.
On the first click, the popup is showing and is hiding 1 second after. An empty hash appends to the url like this : [domain]/test?param1=14%2F03%2F2015#

Then, on second click, the popup is showing correctly.